# How can one create a gallery that adapts to the different sizes of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

In this image:
[image: http://www.autofinesse.co.uk/share-n-shine/]
at this link:

http://www.autofinesse.co.uk/share-n-shine/

There are images of different sizes, the css seems to be generated automatically, i'd like a client to be able to upload to wordpress and not have to worry about the standard sizes of images too much. This gallery is fully aligned for every image, changes height between rows and doesn't make them all the same size.

Is there a library that will allow me to do this? The only way i've been able to do it is with the use of background positioning, which crops the image and also prevents the images being different sizes.

Or is there some sort of javascript algorithm to work this out?

Comment: for this you don't need a javascript library, theres only some small code in CSS required

Comment: @TheDefinitionist can you elaborate? I can't see how you could get every row the exact same width when every image is a different size?

Comment: I'd love to see that CSS too

Comment: @Bakitai If you insist, there you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/40205259/6189002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could give you a css solution but you said for a client on WP.

For that I suggest using a plugin like Unite Gallery which I use for my WP and Joomla clients.

Here is a screen. It also allows for text overlays like the image you posted.

[image]

https://wordpress.org/plugins/unite-gallery-lite/

**Here is a CSS sample using flex**

```css
.flex {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-4by3, .flex-3by4, .flex-1by1, .flex-2by1, .flex-1by2, .flex-3by1, .flex-1by3 {
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-4by3:before, .flex-3by4:before, .flex-1by1:before, .flex-2by1:before, .flex-1by2:before, .flex-3by1:before, .flex-1by3:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.flex-4by3 {
  flex-grow: 1.33333;
  flex-basis: 266.66667px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 426.66667px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/267/200/food");
}
.flex-4by3:before {
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.flex-3by4 {
  flex-grow: 0.75;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 240px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/150/200/food");
}
.flex-3by4:before {
  padding-top: 133.33333%;
}

.flex-1by1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 320px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food");
}
.flex-1by1:before {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.flex-2by1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 400px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 640px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food");
}
.flex-2by1:before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.flex-1by2 {
  flex-grow: 0.5;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 160px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/200/food");
}
.flex-1by2:before {
  padding-top: 200%;
}

.flex-3by1 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-basis: 600px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 960px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/200/food");
}
.flex-3by1:before {
  padding-top: 33.33333%;
}

.flex-1by3 {
  flex-grow: 0.33333;
  flex-basis: 66.66667px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 106.66667px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/67/200/food");
}
.flex-1by3:before {
  padding-top: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-4by3"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by2"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by4"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by4"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by4"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by2"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by3"></div>
  <div class="flex-4by3"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-4by3"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by4"></div>
  <div class="flex-3by4"></div>
  <div class="flex-1by1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2by1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Besides this is for a plugin, it has gaps between the images when you change size

Comment: The demo is a css method, not a result of a plugin. A plugin is your best bet for your WP client.

Comment: I didn't say it is a somewhat result of a  plugin though, however I was the one who +'ed :)

Comment: This worked a charm, thank you. Client is able to maintain as they need :)

Comment: @TheDefinitionist I appreciate your input and + :)

Comment: @Bakitai I am glad it worked out, I use the same for most clients. Very good little app. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://imgur.com/kj4qwHl.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/q6pFhhE.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/ngdnoYI.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/FkrSS5O.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/ux0Om6X.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/2ProEc9.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/iu39yRs.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/gx0iOdT.jpg">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/6kEuRYX.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS (SASS)**

```
@mixin rspv($w) {
  @media screen and (max-width:$w) {
    @if $w==680px {
      img:nth-child(n1) {
        width:100%;
      }
    } @else {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
@mixin grid($pc...) {
  $len:length($pc);
  img {
    vertical-align:top;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    @for $i from 1 through $len {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        width: nth($pc,$i)+'%';
      } 
    }  
  }
}
div {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 100px;
  +grid(26,40.7,33.3,41.9,26.7,31.4,29,38.5,32.5);
  @include rspv(860px) {
    +grid(39,61,45,55,46,54,42.9,57.1,100);
  }
  +rspv(680px);
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

In the `rspv` mixin (responsive) it checks if width meets the `680px` then `(even)` and `(odd)` images will have full size. If not, mixin `grid` will come into play.

Besides normal property:value pairs, `grid` takes width from a given parameter `$pc` (percent) and uses it in the `for` loop. It will iterate through `$i` depending on the length of `$pc` and returns every value from the `$pc` map.

Since all images are inside of the `div`, all mixins will be included there. First `grid` doesn't need a responsive requirement, the second one does, and the last `+rspv(680px)` doesn't need width calculation.

This should work what your link about cars is showing. Not much code. I recommend, get precompiler for CSS. Without that it would be much more code and a lot harder to make up a plan.

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/41rpvg1m/)

Comment: That sort of works, unless you change the images or the order of them. I needed my client to be able to change images around as they please without needed to keep hiring me! This is awesome though, so +1 and definately saving this code for the future.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to change images or order, but ok and thanks